# Redirección sitio web en IIS

Tags: web

Soy nuevo en estos temas, y quería consultar si es posible redireccionar una consulta a un sitio WEB de Microsoft a nivel de IIS.
que al invocar:

> http://web-A/sitio1  vaya a http://web-B/sitio1
> http://web-A/sitio2  vaya a http://web-B/sitio2
>
> etc....

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas  agregrar  una etiqueta al  config de tu app

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://web-B/sitio2" exactDestination="true" />
</system.webServer>
```